# How to receive e-mail notifications for Facebook messages?

Tags: facebook, email, notifications

I would like to receive an e-mail every time someone sends me a Facebook message. I would like to spend less time on Facebook, but I don't want to miss the messages sent to me.

I have checked the '*notifications*' tab in settings, and there are a lot of actions I can receive notifications for, but 'receiving a Facebook message' doesn't appear to be one of these.

I know this was possible in the past, or even default, but I can't manage to turn it back on. I simply cannot find it in the settings.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers suggested using the *Report a Problem* tool, but after submitting that form it said they don't guarantee a response, which pretty much meant it's not a support option and I'm still on my own. Then I found a help page that seemed relevant:

> **I don't receive notifications for new messages.**
>
> If you aren't getting notifications when you receive a new message, please let us know.

And the *let us know* portion linked to the page that says:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7wCi.png]

> **Missing Notifications**
>
> If you aren't getting message notifications, you've come to the right place. Please use this form to tell us more.

Here's the address: [facebook.com/help/contact/230396490410489](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/230396490410489)

After submitting I got a popup box saying they'll get back to me.

Until I can personally confirm that it worked, this is an option.

Comment: Next time it would be better to wait until you're confident either way of the outcome before posting an answer, otherwise it may be flagged as a non-answer and deleted

Comment: I did actually hear from them - I got a generic on-site notification saying that they value all feedback and can't personally get back to everyone. And few weeks later I actually got a Facebok e-mail about my friend liking someone else's photo. I'm not active on Facebook so I guess if I was I would've received more e-mails.